# How to change navigation bar button color?

Tags: android, android-theme, navigationbar

The primary color of my application is white and hence my navigation bar color is also white. My problem is that navigation bar buttons are also white in color. How do I make sure that buttons are visible in white background. The app theme I have used is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

I have tried using different theme but none seem to be working so far.

Can anyone tell me how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: are you talking about the navigation buttons which we have in the bottom of the screen?

Comment: No he means toolbar buttons

Comment: Use a custom icon for this

Comment: Try this code getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.arrowleft)

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT Yes I meant the navigation button at bottom of screen. Not the toolbar buttons.

Comment: So you want to turn your buttons at bottom of screen black so that they can be easily viewed.

Comment: @Glinda I have added an answer. Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Oreo and above you can try this:

```
View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
```

For this to take effect, the window must request FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS but not FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION.

You can also refer here for more details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR

Also there is another approach:

you can achieve it by placing this in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this for android versions below oreo?